# Python Jupyter: `%run -d` (debug mode) doesn't work

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I am trying to run a script in a Jupyter Notebook in debug mode with the magic `%run -d  "/home/dev/filename.py"`.

I receive error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'f_globals'` when doing so.

This would happen with `filename.py` containing only `print("hello world)`. The script itself is irrelevant and the error happens on calling the magic.

To be clear the code that produces the error is the magic `%run -d` itself. You can try to reproduce it in a Jupyter Notebook with any script. For me any script returns that error.

Anyone has experienced the same? Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Don't you think it might be useful to post the code that produces this error (in the form of a [mcve])?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 For the purpose of example, this would happen with `filename.py` containing only `print("hello world)`. The script itself is irrelevant and the error happens on calling the magic.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 To be clear the code that produces the error is the magic `%run -d` itself. You can try to reproduce it in a Jupyter Notebook with any script. For me any script returns that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10030
https://github.com/takluyver/ipython/commit/6b1960d811d25e8f754324259a5b4fd59f8f8162

I t was a bug in the Ipython file that i had to manually edit. Not the easiest for a newbie :S.